# Initialize HuggingFace Bert with random weights

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

How is it possible to initialize BERT with random weights? I want to compare the performance of multilingual vs monolingual vs randomly initialized BERT in a masked language modeling task. While in the former cases it is very straightforward:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM

tokenizer_multi = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-cased')
model_multi = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-cased')
model_multi.eval()

tokenizer_mono = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
model_mono = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
model_mono.eval()
```

I don't know how to load random weights.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try asking on the huggingface forum https://discuss.huggingface.co/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize a random BERT model using the Hugginface capabilites (from the documentation https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.28.1/en/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertConfig)

```
from transformers import BertConfig, BertModel

# Initializing a BERT bert-base-uncased style configuration
configuration = BertConfig()

# Initializing a model (with random weights) from the bert-base-uncased style configuration
model = BertModel(configuration)

# Accessing the model configuration
configuration = model.config
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function:

```py
def randomize_model(model):
    for module_ in model.named_modules(): 
        if isinstance(module_[1],(torch.nn.Linear, torch.nn.Embedding)):
            module_[1].weight.data.normal_(mean=0.0, std=model.config.initializer_range)
        elif isinstance(module_[1], torch.nn.LayerNorm):
            module_[1].bias.data.zero_()
            module_[1].weight.data.fill_(1.0)
        if isinstance(module_[1], torch.nn.Linear) and module_[1].bias is not None:
            module_[1].bias.data.zero_()
    return model
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).